# How can I save realtime data from external source to excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Excel can stream live data from an external source on the internet. One example is stock quotes from google finance. many trading platforms also allow linking to excel. So one can see in excel, a row of data constantly refreshing with new data I.e price of the stock, last traded time, volume etc
I'll post a pic here:

[image: live streaming into excel]

The above image, being an image is static but the 2nd, 3rd and 4th cells update once per second
My question is: how to save the data so that after the day ends I have a full days worth of data captured. maybe into the adjacent sheet or on the same sheet

The full day's data would look something like this:

[image: data saved after a certain interval of time]

Please note that the above two pics are of different stocks. I just posted them so as to provide with an outline of what my requirement is. also please ignore the white space in the first image(that space should have been edited out)

Comment: there is a related question here: http://superuser.com/questions/740189/how-do-i-create-a-dynamically-growing-graph-which-ignores-empty-tail-cells?rq=1

Comment: another way to think of this question is: how can i use the RTD function in excel to create a realtime graph of the data(in excel itself)

Comment: as of now, i've posted this question to 3 other popular excel forums and not yet received a single answer! its such a simple requirement

Comment: probably this is what you seek : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405912/macro-to-store-rtd-data